# Retrieving Node.js Module from GitHub - Error: ENOENT, open package/package.json'

Tags: node.js, npm

To my understanding, the 'npm' knows about git, so i can use it to retrieve Node.js modules from github. So, I have created Node.js module and hosted it at github. When I try to install it in my Node.js project as following:

```
npm install git://github.com/git-user/repo.git
```

then i am getting following error:

```
 Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/kapa/tmp/npm-12237/1371351143597-0.9469406655989587/package/package.json'
...
code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
```

What am i doing wrong and how to install module from github? Thank You

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Does your repository contain a proper `package.json` file? That is required to have your repository handled as an npm module.

Comment: Thank you Peter. the package.json was missing and 'npm init' created one with all of the dependencies

Comment: In my case I was executing `npm install` from one directory above the one containing the `package.json` file. Oops. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be using a `.zip` file. NPM doesn't support it and it may throw an error. Here is what you can use: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html#DESCRIPTION

Comment: in case of fetching from github removing .zip from the url and replacing "archive" with "tarball" solved the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

**For those who already have a package.json file:**

Just in case you didn't notice the comments below the accepted answer, you need to make sure you are inside your app folder to be able to run `npm start`. It seems to be a common mistake to accidentally run `npm start` from one directory above. Hope this helps.