# Node failes to install tools via "npm install"

Tags: node.js

I am running  windows 7 - 64 bit

after running latest node installer, and typing

> npm install

I get errors

```
Couldn't read dependencies
ENOENT open ....packages.json
```

wtf?

Comment: Can you show us the `packages.json` in question?

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130020/retrieving-node-js-module-from-github-error-enoent-open-package-package-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install` installs the dependencies listed in your `package.json`. The error you get means that the folder you are currently in does not have a `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be using a file called package.json (not packages.json) to follow convention. Also that file may be missing. Please create a package.json and check the notation is correct in the JSON file.

'npm install' looks for dependencies listed in package.json file and then pulls them from npm registry into the local ./node_modules folder.