# npm start error npm-debug.log file missing

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to execute `npm start` with **git bash** but I am receiving this message:

```
Error -4058", "ENOENT package .json
```

and

```
Please include the following file C:\..\npm-debug.log
```

I've tried these things that haven't worked:

- clearing the npm cache
- updated to the latest npm

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving Node.js Module from GitHub - Error: ENOENT, open package/package.json'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130020/retrieving-node-js-module-from-github-error-enoent-open-package-package-json)

Answer (score 1):

You have not created the package.json file yet. You need to create it and then add the script "start" to it.

example of package.json:-

```
{
    name: "<Your package name>"
    "scripts": {
         "start": "<You start command>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this in package.json:

`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install" 
  }
```

`

as #Golak_Sarangi said.Thanks dude,It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

download this file

```
Fortinet_CA_SSLProxy.crt
```

and save in some folder. In terminal:

```
sudo cp Fortinet_CA_SSLProxy.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates
```

and then try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

A new dialog box appear in terminal select `enter` and select `Fortinet_CA_SSLProxy.crt` option and click ok.

Note: Select the option using spacebar.